# Why are two strings look equal but they're not?

Tags: php, string-comparison

My PHP code:

```
$hello = "Hello, world! ";
echo $string1 = sprintf("%'#-20s\n", $hello); // Displays "Hello, world! ######"
echo $string2 = str_pad($hello, 20, "#");     // Displays "Hello, world! ######"
echo ($string1 == $string2) ? "Indeed they're equal" : "They're not equal";
                                              //  Displays "They're not equal"
echo strcmp($string1, $string2); // Displays "-1", which (according to PHP Manual)
                                 // means that $string1 is less than $string2
```

Any reason why the strings `$string1` & `$string2` aren't equal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

because there is a new line `\n` in the first `sprintf`.